# Sort Collection Based on Sub Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im setting up a filestore on firebase.

Lets say I have a Collection named countries with the names of the countries in it, inside it I have another collection named states and then Cities so, if I ask where do you live the person can say USA, whis is the doc AI897DJdjusKD8. Based on that I can do

db.collection("cities").doc("AI897DJdjusKD8").collection("states").get

and the person can select from it Texas which is doc DJDffjdi983uyeF and from it we have

db.collection("cities").doc("AI897DJdjusKD8").collection("states").doc("DJDffjdi983uyeF").colection("city").get

and from it the person can select a city, from example Huston, which is doc 5jsi73Fu3TG. Afer typing the address I do a different collection called address with the name of the street, the number of the building, the id of the city stated before and the user id.

Question: Is there a way I can go backwards on the chain to show the information on display. Knowing the user id I know the addres, leading me to the city, which gives me the state and so on? So I can display:

Name:

Lastname:

Address:

City:

State:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can go backwards on the chain to show the information on display. Knowing the user id I know the addres, leading me to the city, which gives me the state and so on?

No, you cannot! Queries in Cloud Firestore are shallow, they only get documents from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and other collections or subcollections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

Beside the existing properties, the most simple solution I can think of, would be to add  the `City` and `State` as extra properties of the document.